# How can i determine my tables priority order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to organize my tables and make a list for usage. What kind of criteria (dependency, fill factor, read/write rate, record count) can i use? I want to protect my database from deadlock...

For example: at simple, i have four tables in my database

```
a table : 4 dependencies
b table : 2 dependencies
c table : 2 dependencies
d table : No dependency
```

If i want to write a stored procedure, which table used firstly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C = Check Constraint
D = Default or Default Constraint
F = Foreign Key Constraint
L = Log
Fn = Scalar Function
If = Inlined Table Function
P = Stored Procedure
Pk = Primary Key Constraint
Rf = Replication Filter Stored Procedure 
S = System Table
Tf = Table Function
Tr = Trigger
U = User Table
Uq = Unique Constraint 
V = View

SELECT DISTINCT SysObjects.Name 'Table Name', 
                Procedures.Name 'Stored Procedure'
           FROM SysObjects 
           JOIN (SysObjects Procedures    
           JOIN SysDepends     
             ON Procedures.Id = SysDepends.Id) 
             ON SysDepends.DepId = SysObjects.Id
          WHERE SysObjects.XType = 'U'     
-- Change XType Values here using chart above     
            AND Procedures.XType = 'P'
       GROUP BY SysObjects.Name, 
                SysObjects.Id, 
                Procedures.Name
       ORDER BY SysObjects.Name ASC
```

Taken from [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/dhite/archive/2007/12/02/sql-query-to-find-table-dependencies.aspx).

Comment: i think, it is not enough for finding or determining to priority order. but i will mark this as answer... thanks again.